# How to print a parent with their children, given a child value that it's unique in Firebase?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've made an agenda with the following values:

```
Contac1
    Name: ""
    Age: ""
    Phone: 11 --> This number it's check if it's unique
Contact2 this key it's generated in incremental way 
    Name: ""
    Age: ""
    Phone: 12
```

I'm triying this:

```
def search():
  
    tlf = verification('TLF number: ', 0)
    if tlf < 0:
        print("ERROR")
        return 
        
    ref = db.reference('Agenda')
    query = ref.order_by_child('Phone').equal_to(tlf).get() 
    
    if len(query)!=0:
        key = list(query.keys())[0]
        for i in ref.get()[key]:
            print(key,'\n')
            for j in ref.get()[key][i].items():
                print("\t ",j,":",ref.get()['Agenda'][i][j])
    else:
        print("No results.")
```

I'm specting something like this:

```
 Contact3
    Name: xxxxx
    Age : 12
    Phone : 123456789
```